# jQuery AJAX JSON autorefresh display data using animation not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have jQuery autorefresh using AJAX and JSON.

```
setInterval(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "d1",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                var n = jsonStr.length;
                var html = "<ul class='table2'>";

                for(var x = 0; x < n; x++)
                {
                    //alert(jsonStr[x].badgeID);
                    html += "<li><div class='td' style='width: 10%; text-align: center; border-right: 3px solid #455f51;'>" + jsonStr[x].badgeID + "</div><div class='td' style='width: 40%; border-right: 3px solid #455f51;'>" + jsonStr[x].employeeName + "</div></li>" ;
                }

                $("#d1").html(html);
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
```

That function will be display the data to id #d1

And now I have jQuery animation when the data will be display.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
        function AnimateList($listItems, index, callback) {
            if (index >= $listItems.length) {
                $listItems.closest("ul").fadeOut(function() {
                    $listItems.css("opacity",0); //reset
                    callback(); //next list
                });
                return;
            }

            $listItems.eq(index).animate({left:0, opacity:1},2000, function() {
                AnimateList($listItems, index+1, callback)
            });
        }

        function FadeLists($lists, index) {
            if (index >= $lists.length) index = 0;

            var $currentList = $lists.eq(index);
            $currentList.fadeIn(function() {
                AnimateList($currentList.find("li"), 0, function() { FadeLists($lists, index + 1) });
            }) 
        }

        var $allLists = $("ul")
        FadeLists($allLists, 0);
    });
```

When page loaded, the data is not show (the data will be show using that animation).

Example animation you can see to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qts6b5/)

HTML

```
<div id="d1"></div>
```

Comment: Well on document load, you have nothing in your div... so nothing can be animated. You want the animation to be launched at each interval ? Every 3 seconds ?

Comment: Yes, because the data load will be from Ajax jSon. So after loaded from Ajax jSon then animate it. If new data added, so it will be added automatically. Is it possible? It means auto refresh using animation to show the data, so when there is new data it will follow to be animation

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call your FadeList after each ajax load, not on document load. Here i removed the ajax part but this is the same thing :

```js
function getList()
  {
    var jsonStr = [0,1,2,3,4] ;

    var ul = jQuery('<ul></ul>') ;
    jQuery(jsonStr).each(function(k,v) {
      ul.append('<li>'+v+'</li>') ;
    }) ;
    $("#d1").append(ul);

    ul.find('li').css({
      'opacity':0,
      'left':'100%',
    }).each(function(){
      // For each "li" in your new UL, animate them from right to left.
      // To make them animate 1 by 1, you don't need to have a timeout or a callback :
      // .index() tells you wich li it is (first, second...) in your loop, so you can just animate at 200*index and they will animate from 0 to each 200ms.
      jQuery(this).animate({
        'opacity':1,
        'left':0,
      },200*jQuery(this).index()) ; 
    }) ;
}

jQuery(document).on('ready',function(){
  getList() ; // Call your getList on load
}) ;

// Call your getList each 3 seconds
setInterval(getList, 3000) ;
```

```css
ul{list-style:none; position:relative ; overflow:hidden; }
ul>li { position:relative ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for your answer. Tested it but I have issue now, when I add new data, it's not show(it will show only 2 data), I think you know it's because the interval time. What I want, if new data added, so the data will show how much it added. Please advice.

Comment: You want to keep previous data and add each 3 seconds new datas at the end ?

Comment: You know, the ajax function will be refresh after 2 seconds. So it will always loop the function, that's why another data can't be show. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure i understand it but take a look at my edit. You have to make sure your ajax function (wich fill jsonStr) only get the last added values, and don't get all values at each call.